# Symfony/DRY - check if user is granted in every action

Tags: symfony, dry

I'm using this code to check if a user is granted in my Symfony application :

```
 $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');

 if($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') ){
     $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
 } else {
     return $this->render('IelCategoryBundle:Category:home.html.twig');
 }
```

I have to ckeck this in almost every CRUD action that I'm writing (edit, delete, ...).

I feel not DRY at all (no play on words ;-)). Is there a better way to check this in many actions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JMSSecurityExtraBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/jms/security-extra-bundle) provides the [@Secure](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/1.2/annotations#secure) annotation which eases checking for a certain user-role before invoking a controller/service method.

```
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation as SecurityExtra;

/** @SecurityExtra\Secure(roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") */
public function yourAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to rely on `Kernel` event listeners: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html.

Implement your listener as a service and then you could set `$this->user` to desired value if `isGranted` results `TRUE`. Later on, you could easily retrieve the value within the controller using:

```
$myServiceListener->getUser();
```

On the other hand, if check fails you could easily redirect user to your `home.html.twig`.